# How to do Laravel base64 image table column String length 5mb

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

```
$table->string('ProfilePhoto',6000000)->change();
```

> Error in this code: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

I want to do `ProfilePhoto` column size 5 mb. How can I do?

Comment: Change string to text type.

Comment: You really shouldn't store files into the database. Store them in the filesystem, and store their *location* in the database.

Comment: But, I want to save to database.

Comment: You should store the file in filesystem and then make a reference to it in the database, and to save long text or big data in the database change the row type to text.

Comment: @YunusGüneş You really don't. It's a massive waste of computing resources to store files in the database, with zero benefits.